# Wordpress PHP if only works when logged in

Tags: php

For some reason this code is only working when I'm logged into my Wordpress site. Does anyone have any ideas to what I'm doing wrong with this php if statement? Here is the url I'm viewing this code on - http://www.rsre.com/residential/

```
<?php if ($property['idxyn'] == 'Yes from Innovia'): ?>
  <div class="col-xs-12" style="margin-top: 12px;">
    <center><img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.rsre.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/IDX-logo.gif" alt="IDX Logo"></center>
  </div>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php if ($property['idxyn'] == 'Yes from WRIST'): ?>
  <div class="col-xs-12" style="margin-top: 12px;">
    <center><img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.rsre.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/wrist-idx.gif" alt="IDX Logo"></center>
  </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: User `var_dump($property['idxyn']);` before the if to check what that variable contains at runtime when you're not logged in.

Comment: The if statement looks good, the point is to know how you populate $property

Comment: I'd say that the part of the code you are showing above, is within a part of some code containing <?php if ( is_user_logged_in() ) { ... } ?>

Comment: And also try using `define('WP_DEBUG', true);` in your wp-config.php file (the define is already present with a value of false). Most likely  this will show you that the `$property` is either not set at all or incomplete.

Comment: P.S.: You're example code gives us very little to work with, I have noo idea what `$property` is and where it comes from.

Comment: As Ole above said, either the code is being ran within a is_user_logged_in() block, or there is a hook only calling the pasted code if a user is logged in.